# Loading bundled resources in Android Native Module - by request from React Native

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, android-resources

I created an Android native module that composes an image from several other image files.

My React Native app invokes said module with the **names** of the images to use.
They are located in the `res/` folder, and thus are accessible to the native module. **The module itself calls `Resources.getIdentifier(...)` to load them.**

However, the official documentation has this line under `getIdentifier`:

> Note: use of this function is discouraged. It is much more efficient to retrieve resources by identifier than by name.

**How can the React Native JS code know the resource ID?**